# R: Replacing Factor Variables with Numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
factor_1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
factor_2 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE")
factor_3 <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE")

var_1 <- as.factor(sample(factor_1, 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))
var_2 <- as.factor(sample(factor_2, 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))
var_3 <- as.factor(sample(factor_3, 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))
var_4 <- rnorm(1000,10,10)
var_5 <- rnorm(1000,10,10)

my_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5)

  var_1 var_2 var_3     var_4     var_5
1     B    AA   EEE 13.645347 13.058532
2     E    AA   DDD  6.845906 -5.503625
3     D    CC   DDD 25.521964 10.438531
4     A    BB   DDD 18.050013 -5.040709
5     D    EE   AAA 21.583362  1.269998
6     D    BB   AAA 14.797192 11.924158
```

**Imagine we only have "my_data" - I want to replace all the factors with integers.**

Currently, I am doing this manually:

First, I created a "dictionary" that maps factors ("levels") to integers "id"):

```
levels_1 = data.frame(id = 1:length(levels(my_data$var_1)), levels_1 = levels(my_data$var_1))
levels_2 = data.frame(id = 1:length(levels(my_data$var_2)), levels_2 = levels(my_data$var_2))
levels_3 = data.frame(id = 1:length(levels(my_data$var_3)), levels_3 = levels(my_data$var_3))
```

Then, I tried to write a code that uses this "dictionary" to make the replacements:

```
my_data$var_1 <- factor(my_data$var_1, labels=levels_1$levels_1, levels = levels_1$id)
my_data$var_2 <- factor(my_data$var_2, labels=levels_2$levels_2, levels = levels_2$id)
my_data$var_3 <- factor(my_data$var_3, labels=levels_3$levels_3, levels = levels_3$id)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in factor(my_data$var_1, labels = levels_1$levels_1, levels = levels_1$id) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 5
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this problem - and in general, is there a "faster" way to do this for many variables without manually making these dictionaries and lookups ?**

The final output would look something like this:

```
  var_1 var_2 var_3     var_4     var_5
1     2    1   5  13.645347 13.058532
2     5    1   4   6.845906 -5.503625
3     4    3   4  25.521964 10.438531
4     1    2   4  18.050013 -5.040709
5     4    4   1  21.583362  1.269998
6     4    2   1 14.797192 11.924158
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps showing your expected output helps (for a smaller sample datasets, 10k rows seems a bit unnecessary as far as sample data are concerned). Are you perhaps asking for something like `my_data %>% mutate(across(is.factor, as.integer))`?

Comment: @ Mauritis Evers: Please see the edits! Thanks!

Comment: @stats_noob Should the results be purely `integer` or `factor` of 1:5?

Comment: @benson23: I think for now it doesnt matter - let's say integer?

Comment: I get no error with above code, not sure what is the problem

Comment: Consider starting a new Rsession. Or even consider reinstalling R

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to change your factor into integer, `as.numeric` is already enough. The factor will be changed into numeric based on the order of the factor level.

**As suggested by @Maurits Evers, I've changed my original `as.numeric` to `as.integer`.**

```
library(dplyr)

my_data %>% mutate(across(var_1:var_3, as.integer))

 var_1 var_2 var_3     var_4     var_5
1     1     3     3 16.317711 26.484805
2     5     3     2 -5.106064 14.346322
3     5     1     4 15.734128 11.340518
4     1     1     2  8.125220 25.393141
5     5     5     1 11.603335  5.525315
6     5     4     4  6.238757 16.657790
```

Comment: @ benson23: Thank you so much! Just a question - is it possible to rewrite my_data %>% mutate(across(var_1:var_3, as.numeric)) as my_data %>% mutate(across(c(var_1, var_2, var_3), as.numeric)) ? Suppose the factor variables are scattered throughout the data frame - is there a more general way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @stats_noob Yes, if you have a vector of colnames, you can do `mutate(across(colnames, as.numeric))`. `across(c(var_1, var_2, var_3)` is also fine.

Comment: my_data %>% mutate(across(c(var_1, var_2, var_3), as.numeric)) - I tried this and it did not work. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @stats_noob it worked on my side, is there any error? is the output not numeric or what?

Comment: @ benson23: no error - but the new data frame remains identical to the old one?

Comment: @stats_noob maybe you want to overwrite your old `my_data` with `my_date <- my_data %>% mutate(across(c(var_1, var_2, var_3), as.numeric))`

Comment: I tried and still nothing ... I will keep trying!

Comment: I recommend using `as.integer` rather than `as.numeric`. Factors are stored as integer values with labels. If you don't want to have to label the columns, you can use `across(where(is.factor), as.integer)` which will convert *all* factor columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone! unfortunately it's still not working I will try again in the morning!

Answer (score 4):

You could create the dictionaries list with `lapply`:

```
dicts <- lapply(my_data,function(x) if (is.factor(x)) {data.frame(id = 1:nlevels(x), 
                                                                  levels = levels(x)
                                                                  )})
dicts[lengths(dicts) == 0] <- NULL

dicts

$var_1
  id levels
1  1      A
2  2      B
3  3      C
4  4      D
5  5      E

$var_2
  id levels
1  1     AA
2  2     BB
3  3     CC
4  4     DD
5  5     EE

$var_3
  id levels
1  1    AAA
2  2    BBB
3  3    CCC
4  4    DDD
5  5    EEE
```

Manual assignement of one factor from this dictionaries list works without error:

```
my_data$var_1 <- factor(my_data$var_1, labels= dicts[["var_1"]][,"levels"], 
                                       levels =  dicts[["var_1"]][,"id"])
```

Answer (score 4):

Find the columns holding a factor with `is.factor`. `levels` give the factor levels for the dictionary. `as.integer` will convert the levels to `integer`.

```
i <- sapply(my_data, is.factor)
dict <- lapply(my_data[i], \(x) setNames(seq_len(nlevels(x)), levels(x)))
my_data[i] <- lapply(my_data[i], as.integer)

head(my_data)
#  var_1 var_2 var_3      var_4     var_5
#1     1     5     2  5.9124237 23.388829
#2     3     2     3 -0.7596536 21.401323
#3     3     5     2 18.5243263  8.526933
#4     4     5     2 21.1761217 19.614810
#5     1     2     3 19.2109621 -3.908547
#6     3     2     2 11.7654375 15.885306

dict
#$var_1
#A B C D E 
#1 2 3 4 5 
#
#$var_2
#AA BB CC DD EE 
# 1  2  3  4  5 

#$var_3
#AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE 
#  1   2   3   4   5
```

Another variant will be to use `unclass` where the `levels` are stored as an `attr`.

```
my_data[] <- lapply(my_data, \(x) if(is.factor(x)) unclass(x) else x)

head(my_data)
#  var_1 var_2 var_3      var_4     var_5
#1     1     5     2  5.9124237 23.388829
#2     3     2     3 -0.7596536 21.401323
#3     3     5     2 18.5243263  8.526933
#4     4     5     2 21.1761217 19.614810
#5     1     2     3 19.2109621 -3.908547
#6     3     2     2 11.7654375 15.885306

. <- attr(my_data$var_1, "levels")
setNames(seq_along(.), .)
#A B C D E 
#1 2 3 4 5 

str(my_data)
#'data.frame':   10000 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ var_1: int  1 3 3 4 1 3 1 1 5 5 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "levels")= chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
# $ var_2: int  5 2 5 5 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "levels")= chr [1:5] "AA" "BB" "CC" "DD" ...
# $ var_3: int  2 3 2 2 3 2 4 2 4 5 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "levels")= chr [1:5] "AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD" ...
# $ var_4: num  5.91 -0.76 18.52 21.18 19.21 ...
# $ var_5: num  23.39 21.4 8.53 19.61 -3.91 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a custom function, `to_integer()`, which takes an arbitrary vector and changes all elements to integers, starting at 1:

```
to_integer <- function(vec) {

  #' Transform vectors of all types safely to integer vectors
  #' @param vec A vector
  #' @return An integer vector

  dreamerr::check_arg(vec, "MBT vector")

  unique_vec <- unique(vec)
  int_vec <- rep(NA, length(vec))
  for (x in seq_along(unique_vec)) {
    int_vec[which(vec == unique_vec[x])] <- x
  }
  as.integer(int_vec)
}
```

This function is 'safer' than using `as.integer` as `as.integer()` will turn character values into NAs.

```
to_integer(c("a", "b", "c"))
# [1] 1 2 3
as.integer(c("a", "b", "c"))
# [1] NA NA NA
# Warning message:
#   NAs introduced by coercion
```

It also works on factors:

```
to_integer(factor(c("a", "b", "c")))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data.table format
setDT(my_data)
# get the names of the columns that are of type factor
cols = my_data[, names(.SD), .SDcols = is.factor]
# convert all factor-columns to integer format
my_data[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: hoping that `names(.SD) := ...` on the LHS will be aded soon.. see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4163